# Tufte symmetric misalligns

Tags: tufte

I am using the `tufte-book` class. After using *symmetric* option, some misalignment do appear.

Please, compile the minimal example to check:

page 7: Perfect
page 43: Misaligned
page 79: Misaligned
page 115: Perfect
page 116: Misaligned

The package `mparhack` didn't help.

Something else is not flat: page 5 should be blank in my opinion. Can the header be deleted?

How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[b5paper,symmetric,raggedright,marginals=justified]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{mparhack}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\begin{fullwidth}\part{Concepts, critics and proposals}\end{fullwidth}
\input{calllipsum.tex}

\begin{fullwidth}\part{Complementary material}\end{fullwidth}
\input{calllipsum.tex}

\begin{fullwidth}\part{Case studies}\end{fullwidth}
\input{calllipsum.tex}

\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The file [calllipsum.tex](http://py4olb.no-ip.org/public/calllipsum.tex) just populates the text with several `\index` entries.

Comment: Auxiliary file is here: http://py4olb.no-ip.org/public/calllipsum.tex

Comment: I see no misalignment in the pages with “Part”, 7, 43 and 79.

Comment: As far as I can see, `fullwidth` only works for something that is completely on an odd page and doesn't behave with material that spans several pages.

Comment: \fullwidth was used with \part for a single line in the whole page.  The output of the compilation with pdfTeX version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 is [here](http://py4olb.no-ip.org/public/testremissive.pdf). Pages 43 cuts letter  "C"; page 79 is not centered; and page 116 cuts the numbers at right side. Without the option "symmetric", the result is ok. There is clearly something wrong with this option.